# Footer moves to the left when zooming in

Tags: css, html

This is the first image with the footer at the bottom right.
First Wanted Location 
http://i.imgur.com/fbS8mWD.png

When I zoom in the scroll bar appears and the footer moves left of the pictures.

Second Unwanted Scaled Location
 
http://i.imgur.com/BrEBA0G.png

I can't do too much editing because the developer is hard headed and won't understand large changes.

What can I do to fix the positioning problem?

```css
/* Genral Styles */
table, td
{
    border-style: none;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-width: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.GridAltItem1:hover
{
    color: white;
    cursor: hand;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 5px solid;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.GridAltItem1nohover
{
    cursor: hand; /* font-weight: bolder;*/
    font-family: Arial;
}
.AjaxCalendar .ajax__calendar_container
{
    border: 1px solid #646464;
    background-color: #C5BEE9 color: red;
}
.ob_iTIE
{
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 500px;
}

.GridAltItem1
{
    background-color: White;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.GridAltItem2nohover
{
    cursor: hand;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.GridAltItem2:hover
{
    color: white;
    cursor: hand;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 5px solid;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.GridAltItem3:hover
{
    color: #FFEF3d;
    cursor: hand;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 5px solid;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.GridAltItem4:hover
{
    color: #FFEF3d;
    cursor: hand;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 5px solid;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.Gridboxsm
{
    color: purple;
    width: 60px;
}
.width795
{
    width: 795px;
}
.width10percent
{
    width: 10%;
}

.width45percent
{
    width: 45%;
}

.width95percent
{
    width: 95%;
}

.width100percent
{
    width: 100%;
}

.height100percent
{
    height: 100%;
}


.aligncenter
{
    text-align: center;
}

.alignleft
{
    text-align: left;
}

.alignright
{
    text-align: right;
}

A:link
{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
A:visited
{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}
A:hover
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
A:active
{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.clickable
{
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Body Styles */

.clsbody
{
    background-color: White;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


.footerRow 
{
     font-size: small;
    font-family: Arial;
   text-align: center; 
   /* margin-left:450px; */
    /*position:absolute;*/
    bottom: 10px; 
}
.footerBackground
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
.footer, a.footer:active, a.footer:link, a.footer:visited
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-small;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.footer:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.copyright
{   font-family  : Arial;
 font-size: small;
 color: #02a194; 
 text-align: center;
}

/* DIV Styles */
DIV.clsDivHidden
{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}

DIV.clsDivVisible
{
    visibility: visible;
}
DIV.clsDivCust
{
    background-color: #A398dc;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: thin outset;
    border-top: thin outset;
    border-left: thin outset;
    border-bottom: thin outset;
}
DIV.clsDivCustSecond
{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #02A194;
}
DIV.clsDivHead
{
    background-color: #FFCC99;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: thin outset;
    border-top: thin outset;
    border-left: thin outset;
    border-bottom: thin outset;
}

/* Buttons */
input.btn
{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: hand;
    color: black;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
input:-webkit-autofill
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px white inset; /* Change the color to your own background color */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}

input:-webkit-autofill:focus
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: /*your box-shadow*/ ,0 0 0 50px white inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}


.clsoption
{
    white-space: pre;
}

.submitbutton
{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: hand;
    color: black;
    background-color: #C5BEE9; /* #C5BEE9*/
}
.submitbutton1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: hand;
    color: white;
    background-color: #937FF5;
}
.submitbutton2
{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: hand;
    color: black;
    background-color: #C5BEE9; /* #C5BEE9*/
}
.submitbutton3
{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: hand;
    background-color: #E6E6F0;
    border-style: Solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-size: x-small;
    height: 20;
}
.passwordbutton
{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: hand;
    color: black;
    background-color: #C5BEE9;
}
.gridtbutton
{
    border-style: Solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.gridbtn1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: hand;
    background-color: #eef;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: Black;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
.gridbutton
{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: hand;
    color: black;
    background-color: #eef;
}
.srcbutton
{
    font-weight: lighter;
    cursor: hand;
    color: purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.submitbutton:hover
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #FFF4C1;/*#F5E964;*/ /*#ded35e;*/
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: Black; /*white*/
    font-family: Arial;
}
.submitbutton1:hover
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #ded35e; 
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: White;
    font-family: Arial;
}
/* Grid Styles */
.gridheader
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-color: #e8e3a9;
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    cursor: hand;
    border-right: thin outset;
    border-top: thin outset;
    border-left: thin outset;
    border-bottom: thin outset;
}
.gridtop
{
    background-color: #9589D7;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Black;
    text-align: center;
}

.gridhdr
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: left;
    color: #eef;
    cursor: hand;
     
}
.gridhdrsm
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: left;
    color: #eef;
    cursor: hand;
}
.gridhdrright
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: Right;
    color: #eef;
    cursor: hand;
}


.gridrow
{
    border-right: black 2px;
    border-top: black 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-left: black 2px;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: black 2px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica; /* background-color: #ffffe0;   background-color:#eee8aa */
}

.gridrowselected
{
    border-right: black 2px;
    border-top: black 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border-left: black 2px;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: black 2px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    background-color: darkkhaki; /*  background-color:white */
}


/* Table styles */
.MasterTbl
{
    border: solid 1px #2E8B57;
    width: 795px;
}
.MasterHeader
{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #02a194;
}
.mastersub
{
    height: 124px;
}
.tblbox
{
    border: solid 1px #a398dc;
    background-color: #E6E6F0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tblbox1
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #a398dc;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.tblbox2
{
    border: solid 1px #a398dc;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 22px;
    width: 400px;
    font-size: small;
}

.tblbox3
{
    border: solid 1px #a398dc;
    background-color: #E6E6F0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 700px;
    padding: 5;
}
.tblbox4
{
    background-image: url('../../Images/Graduatecap2.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.tblbox41
{
    background-image: url('../../Images/Graduatecap.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.tbl4
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.tbl5
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

TR.classRow
{
    background-color: beige;
}

TD.clsTDHeader
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-color: #e8e3a9;
    border-right: #999999 2px outset;
    border-top: #e4ecf5 1px outset;
    border-left: #e4ecf5 1px outset;
    border-bottom: #adc3e4 1px outset;
    cursor: hand;
}




TD.clsTDData
{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
}

TD.clsTDLabel
{
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
}

TD.clsTDLabelLeft
{
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
}

TD.clsTDLabelBold
{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    color: #2E8B57;
    text-align: right;
}


TD.clsTDValue
{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #02A194;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
}

TD.clsTDRed
{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
}

TR.clsTabHeader
{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    background-color: #B6A467;
    text-align: center;
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Title Styles */
.PageTitle
{
    font-size: 15pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2E8B57;
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
}
.PageFooter
{
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #A398DC; /*#8A75FF;*/
}

.SubtitleCenter
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px; /* padding-left: 10px;*/
    background-color: White;
    text-align: center;
}
.SubtitleCenter1
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #02a194;
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: White;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.SubtitleCenter3
{
    font-size: 13pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px; /* padding-left: 10px;*/
    background-color: White;
    text-align: center;
}
.SubtitleLeft
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
}

.banner
{
    background-image: url('../../Images/great-filler.jpg');
    text-align: center;
}

.portletTitle_l
{
    background-image: url(/ecjcgreat/images/tab_green_l_vi_shrink.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 6px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}
.portletTitle_r
{
    background-image: url(/ecjcgreat/images/tab_green_r_vi_shrink.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: white;
}
.portletTitle
{
    background-image: url(/ecjcgreat/images/tab_green_m_vi.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif; /* 'Bernard MT Condensed' */
    color: #004400;
    background-color: white;
    width: 90px;
}
.portletTitle_l_sel
{
    background-image: url(/ecjcgreat/images/tab_green_l_vi_shrink_2.gif);
    width: 6px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}
.portletTitle_r_sel
{
    background-image: url(/ecjcgreat/images/tab_green_r_vi_shrink_2.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: white;
}
.portletTitle_sel
{
    background-image: url(/ecjcgreat/images/tab_green_m_vi_2.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif; /* 'Bernard MT Condensed' */
    color: #004400;
    background-color: white;
    width: 90px;
}

/* TEXT PROPERTIES */

.text_table
{
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: #484848;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    padding: 5px;
}

.text_table_font
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #484848;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    padding: 3px;
}
.text_font
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
}

.login_header
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: medium;
    color: purple;
    background-color: White;
    /*text-align: center;*/
}
.login_txt
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: right;
    color: purple;
    background-color: White;
   /* width: 64%;*/
}

h2.portletTitleText
{
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif; /* 'Bernard MT Condensed' */
    color: #004400;
    text-align: center;
}

TD.clsRadiolabel
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
}

.TextWOBorder
{
    border-right: 0px solid;
    border-top: 0px solid;
    border-left: 0px solid;
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


TD.clsTDFont
{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
    text-align: left;
}


.linkbutton
{
    font: bold 11px Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e8e3a9;
    color: black;
    border-top: #e8e3a9 1px outset;
    border-right: #e8e3a9 1px outset;
    border-bottom: #e8e3a9 1px outset;
    border-left: #e8e3a9 1px outset;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


.linkbutton:hover
{
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background: #B6A467;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: White;
}

select
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/*::-moz-selection
{
    background: #0C0;
    color: #f00;
}
::selection
{
    background: #6374AB;
    color: #F00;
}*/


option
{
    width: 100px;
}

#Table1
{
    height: 34px;
}
.style2
{
    width: 64%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style3
{
    color: Black;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.style4
{
    width: 240px;
    height: 97px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style5
{
    width: 775px;
    height: 97px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style6
{
    width: 240px;
    height: 97px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style7
{
    width: 455px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style31
{
    color: purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style32
{
    color: purple;
    width: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style40
{
    width: 185px;
    color: purple;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style41
{
   /* width: 185px;*/
    color: purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style411
{
    width: 200px;
    color: White; /* #937FF5; */
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style413
{
    width: 275px;
    color: purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style414
{
    width: 25px;
    color: purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style415
{
    width: 450px;
    color: purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style417
{
    width: 400px;
    color: white; /* #937FF5; */
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style418
{
    width: 185px;
    color: purple;
    font-size: medium;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style42
{
    width: 75px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style43
{
    width: 175px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style44
{
    width: 250px;
    color: #02A194;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style45
{
    width: 30px;
    color: Purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style46
{
    width: 400px;
    color: red;
    font-family: Arial;
}


.style51
{
    height: 26px;
    width: 165px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style52
{
    width: 643px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style61
{
    width: 300px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style99
{
    color: green;
    background-color: #eef;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style991
{
    color: black;
    background-color: #eef;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style100
{
    color: purple;
    width: 387px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style101
{
    width: 201px;
    color: purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.style102
{
    width: 306px;
    color: purple;
    font-family: Arial;
}
A:link
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
A:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
A:active
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
A:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Menu Classes*/
.has-popup
{
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.level2
{
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
.level3
{
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #DDDDF9;
    border: 1px solid #ccd;
}
.has-popup, .level2
{
    border: 1px solid #ccd;
    background-color: #eef;
}

.dynamic
{
}
```

```html
<div id="footer1">
            <table width="97%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="width: 95%;">
                    </td>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap">
                        <font color="#02a194">© 2013 TEST TEST TEST </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
```

Comment: could you add the url where this problem is ? in the snippet i cannot see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will fix your code:

```
.footer1{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 bottom: 0px 

 }
```

Some tips:

html5 introduced some new tags one of them is the footer tag, this one is the best way to add a footer to your page, so instad of using a div with a footer1 class, you should use the "footer" tag. here the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp

and please when your posting a question is better if you post the css that is linked to the html thing that you need to fix, cause here you posted the whole css code where we just need the .footer1 code!

good luck!

Comment: I can't post the css link because I'm not sure if I'm allowed too. I will attempt your tip and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Okay it worked! But I want it to stay at the bottom left of the screen up to some point where it stops before passing the icons.

Comment: you could add to the .footer1 this code {left:0px;}

Comment: It still moves to the left when I zoom in. If i scroll to the right the footer is basicly now in the middle. I want it to stay on the bottom right absolutely. I'm sorry about the limited amount of information I'm providing you.